# How to compute maximum width/height of the element?

Tags: c#, wpf, size

Let's say you have WPF window with one element that changes it size as the window resizes, say `DockPanel` with two elements. You maximize the window, and the second element gets maximized as well. So not I could read its height/width and those would be maximum values (this is good enough for my purpose, so I don't have to worry if the taskbar takes some space or similar issues).

OK, but let's get back to the freshly started window -- I would like to **compute** the max width/height of the given element without actually resizing the window, just pure computation. Is it doable? How?

Comment: Of what element do you want to compute the width and height? Based on what informaton would you like to compute that? Can you not simply acces properties of that element and get the width and height?

Comment: @pijemcolu, of `ListBox`, `TextBox`, any element. `Height` gives you the current height, not the maximum.

Comment: Based on what do you consider a value to be maximum width height for an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to know the maximum size the window could be. That would be the size of the screen then. Screensize is an available value:

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

Perhaps you could do something like this:

- Get size of window
- Get size of element
- calculate offset (windowSize - elementSize)
- Get Screen size
- calculate maximum size (screenSize - offset)

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to get max width/height of given element of the window, without maximizing entire window. It could be `ListBox` for example.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Could perhaps be a hint into the right direction

Comment: You are great! "Of course" -- when you know the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a test window which will appear as maximised, get its width and height and then close it.
This can be done every time you need to calculate values or at the start of the application, assuming you will check whether screen resolution has not changed.

```
private void GetMaximumWidthAndHeight(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var testWindow = new Window();
    testWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    testWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    testWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    testWindow.Show();

    var maximizedWindowHeight = testWindow.ActualHeight;
    var maximizedWindowWidth = testWindow.ActualWidth;

    testWindow.Close();

    var maxToCurrentHeightRatio = maximizedWindowHeight / this.ActualHeight;
    var maxToCurrentWidthRatio = maximizedWindowWidth / this.ActualWidth;

    var maximumElementHeight = element.ActualHeight * maxToCurrentHeightRatio;
    var maximumElementWidth = element.ActualWidth * maxToCurrentWidthRatio;

    // Do something with the values
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but then in my case it is simpler to maximize window on the start and then go to normal. But then of course it would be great to remove resizing altogether.